# How to make promoted links URL relative?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, promoted-links

I'm trying to make a Site Template so that we can easily create subsites.

We are using promoted links on the home page and would like them to be relative to their location instead of static links.

eg.
`/subsite1/SitePages/xyz.aspx` or `/subsite2/SitePages/xyz.aspx`

They cannot all point to the same page. They need to point to their respective subsite page.

Anyone knows a work around?

I've heard of a jQuery hack, but I'm hoping we can avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using jQuery to override the redirect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li[title="Help & FAQ"]').parent().parent().parent().attr("clickaction", "PreventDefaultNavigation(); STSNavigate('helpfaq.aspx'); return false;"); 
    $('li[title="Feedback"]').parent().parent().parent().attr("clickaction", "PreventDefaultNavigation(); STSNavigate('feedback.aspx'); return false;");
});
```

It doesn't look very nice but it works. The way I've done it allows me to only override the two specific links across all sites in the collection.

Comment: I am similar boat but in my case I need that the standard Hyperlink in SP2016 to also accep URL starting with cdb:// whereas at moment, it will not accept any URL unless it starts with https://  :( how can I use yor code for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to write that in an event receiver. You could create an event receiver that whenever a new site has been created, to create any of the links relative to the web, such as:

```
SPList targetList = targetWeb.Lists["Promoted Links"];
SPListItemCollection items = targetList.Items;
SPListItem item = items.Add();
item["Title"] = "NewLink";
item["Link Location"] = properties.Web.Url + "/"
item["Background Image Location"] = properties.Web.Url + "/_layouts/images/customimage.png";
item.Update();
```

Comment: With my limited knowledge I wouldn't be able to implement that. Also my SP site is not a VS package thus I cannot change the code via the SP UI.